# How to change cell value with data in visible area of Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, scroll

I hope to explain as best I can.

For example, I have a scrollable horizontal daily calendar, in an Excel sheet. In that, I have a left column with some items, and the sheet is "frozen" so that this column is always visible with any horizontal calendar scroll.

So imagine that I scrolled the calendar, and a different year is in the visible scrolled area. On that (always visible) left column, I want a cell to change the value to the current visible year.

I have searched over forums, but no luck or even a first idea to start with.

Thanks.

Comment: So basically, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aa2H.gif)? (I obviously manually changed the date in column A, but that's what you want automatically to change, as the columns are scrolled through?)  What have you tried?

Comment: Hm, looking [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm), it may be possible to detect the scroll.  However, could we tweak your request a little? What if when you scroll, you always select a cell? That way you could use a `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event and we'd have an easier time doing this.

Comment: Hey "Batman"! Ya, it's your example. I haven't tried anything, because I had no idea where to start. The tweaking you suggest isn't possible, since the sheet is to be editable, and for others to use besides me.

Comment: That's what I mean - I can't, without some really crazy stuff, think of a way to do it simply via scrolling.  But, what if you scroll (and it keeps the old year), but then when the user clicks a cell, it updates the year shown?

Comment: Well, I'm going to try something (although it's a bit over the top). Using visiblerange go get the left most cell address (and value) of the visible range (of course!) that is in the scrollable pane, and a timer to keep the pretended cell updated. Don't know if a continuous running timer affects too much an excel, possible heavy, file.

Comment: How are you going to trigger the visible range to recalculate? ...a timer might work, except I *think* you'll have to run the macro the whole time, no?

Comment: It will have to be a timer started in the book open event, and yes, working the whole as long as the book is opened. Don't know if that's the best option, in terms of file integrity (not prone to error or fail) and quick in function.